# Return all values when a condition value is NULL

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following very simple query:

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = %s'
```

And I'm calling it from a python sql wrapper, in this case psycopg:

```
cur.execute(query, (row_id))
```

The thing is that if row_id is `None`, I would like to get all the rows, but that query would return an empty table instead.
The easy way to approach this would be:

```
if row_id:
    cur.execute(query, (row_id))
else:
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM table1")
```

Of course this is non idiomatic and gets unnecessarily complex with non-trivial queries. I guess there is a way to handle this in the SQL itself but couldn't find anything. What is the right way?

Comment: Don't try this on a table with lots of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [**COALESCE**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html) function as below

```
query = 'SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = COALESCE(%s,id)'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = %s OR %s IS NULL
```

But depending how the variable is forwarded to the query it might be better to make it 0 if it is None

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE id = %s OR %s = 0
```